# How to check if my ASP.NET Core is running on Azure?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I want to write code once, run on Synology/Azure/localdebug.
I've tried the if WEBSITE_HOSTNAME.Contains("Azure"), seems failed.

Comment: And why do you actually care? What is the difference between those three environments?

Comment: `WEBSITE_HOSTNAME` doesn't return the hosting provider's name. It returns the application's configured [HOST name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host), which is sent as an HTTP header by clients on every request, eg  `myapp.mydomain.com`.

Comment: Besides, `WEBSITE_HOSTNAME` is an environment variable specific to [Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/reference-app-settings?tabs=kudu%2Cdotnet). If  `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_HOSTNAME")` returns a value, chances are you *are* running on Azure. Unless you explicitly set that variable on another environment.

Comment: @GuruStron I want to connect to different database.

Comment: @MingTong different connection string or different database type?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks, so no matter what is in the WEBSITE_HOSTNAME,  can indicate it is on Azure.

Comment: @GuruStron different database type. on Azure I want to use Sqlite for cheap, on Synology I want to use Maria for performance.

Comment: @MingTong just create a custom setting for database type and that's it. Alternatively you can try parse the connection string but I would not go with that approach.

Comment: @GuruStron sorry, what do you mean custom setting, and how can I know when to use which?

Comment: @MingTong you configure what database is used. You don't need to detect the environment. And SQLite is simply *not* meant for such a scenario. It's not a multi-user database, and its files may not persist across calls unless you explicitly store them in some kind of blob storage. SQLite is an embedded (ie run by your own application) database. That means that two concurrent requests will start two database instances.

Comment: @MingTong I mean just use [the configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration), add there some custom key like `DatabaseType` and fill it differently in different environments.

Comment: If anything, it's Synology that should use SQLite because it's unlikely a site stored on a NAS will get a lot of traffic. SQLite allows multiple *read* connections but there can only be one "write" at a time. When that happens, the entire database is locked.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos hmm, yeah, actually it's not a commercial product, it's just my personal hobby project, so for cost reason, I wouldn't use RDS(e.g. Maria/PG/SqlServer). btw, I just put the SQLite in the wwwroot, I don't think SQLite could be put in blob storage for direct access.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos And on my NAS, the Asp.NET Core can only be accessed from my home members, so traffic is acceptable. Thanks for you explanation.

Comment: On a hoster, especially a managed cloud service, your site runs wherever the host infrastructure decides. The machine will change as servers get rotated or sites put to sleep. Only files the hoster knows about will be persisted. This means any data stored in SQLite may be lost after a while, unless you store it to Azure Blob storage.

Comment: If the traffic is low, why use a relational database at all? There are other, cheaper storage options.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "lost for a while", means it is not accessible for a while, cannot be 99.99%? Technilcally, I am new to Azure, if I put the SQLite file in Blog Storage, when do access, need a Authentication, right? it cannot be mouted as a local file.
On my NAS, no concurrent users to access the db, but when I myself feed the db, would have a single way big traffic.

Comment: What you mean running on Azure? Azure VM, Cloud service or web apps?

Comment: @BrandoZhang Web App

Comment: For Azure web apps, I suggest you could get the "HTTP_HOST" environment variable inside your application, this HTTP_HOST normally is the xxxxx.scm.azurewebsites.com, you could check if this contains azurewebsites to see if this is host at the Azure web apps or not

Comment: @BrandoZhang , Thanks, I finally use the solution from Guru Stron.
BTW, the solultion from Panagiotis Kanavos still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to connect to different database type...

I would argue that the easier/more robust approach would be to introduce a special setting in the [configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration) (like `DatabaseType`) and set it to different values for different environments (via appropriate configuration source).